# Ftp con Php problema en descargas

Tags: php, ftp, descarga

necesito descargar archivos de un servidor FTP, y he intentado de varias maneras, logro poner los link de descarga en la pagina y luego al ejecutar me los baja sin problema (salvo que la primera vez me pide usuario y clave tema que no puedo resolver ya que se lo paso desde el código).
Lo que necesito es que se descarguen de forma automática, sin intervención del usuario, y si fuese posible a una carpeta predeterminada y que no sea la que tiene por defecto el explorador. Quizás exista otra manera, la verdad soy nuevo en este tipo de código. Desde ya Muchas Gracias.

```
  $ftp_server = "hospidelahostia.dyndns.org";
  $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
  $ftp_user_name = "minombre";
  $ftp_user_pass = "miclave";
  $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
  ftp_chdir($conn_id, $d);
  $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id,".");
  $x = 0;
  while($x < count($contents)) {
    echo "<a href=ftp://imagenes@hospidelahostia.dyndns.org/".$d.substr($contents[$x],1).">" .'ftp://imagenes@hospidelahostia.dyndns.org/'.$d.substr($contents[$x],1) . "</a><br></br>";
    $x++;
    }
```

Comment: Hasta donde se no puedes cambiar la ruta de descarga de tu navegador desde un script de alguna pagina, ya eso lo haces tu mismo desde tu navegador

Answer (score 0):

Para descargar un archivo automáticamente, puedes usar [`ftp_fget`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-fget.php):

```
$handle = fopen($local_file, 'w'); // local_file es el directorio completo en donde se descarga el archivo remoto
if (ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $remote_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
    // $conn_id - Es el id de conexion que obtienes con ftp_connect
    // $handle - Un apuntador del archivo abierto en el cual almacenar los datos.
    // $remote_file - La ruta del archivo remoto
    // FTP_ASCII - el modo de transferencia
    // 0 - resume_pos, la posición desde la cual se empieza a descargar el archivo remoto.
    echo "Se ha creado el archivo " . $local_file . " </br>";
    fwrite($log, $local_file . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    echo "Ha habido un problema durante la descarga de $remote_file en $local_file 
}
```

Obviamente, para descargar archivo por archivo, debes obtener su ruta de forma dinámica anteriormente.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, con tu ejemplo logre descargar a traves de un bucle, los archivos, pero me los descarga en el servidor xampp htdocs carpeta donde esta el index.php, hay alguna forma de realizar la descarga en una carpeta local de la pc?. desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: `$local_file` es el que debe apuntar al directorio y archivo final. Este es mi ejemplo usado en un directorio dinámico -> `$local_file = 'C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/bowa/temp/'.$rut."/".$sucursal."/".$equipo."/".$fecha."/".$xml;`